# Error with creating table

Tags: mysql, database

This is my statement, I'm getting an error on Customer_T. The error states:

```
"01:22:05   DROP TABLE customer_t   Error Code: 1051. Unknown table 'energyefficient.customer_t'    0.016 sec"

CREATE TABLE Customer_t
             (CustomerID   INT               NOT NULL,
              Name         VARCHAR(45)       NOT NULL,
              Address      VARCHAR(256)              ,
              Email        VARCHAR(100)              ,    
              Phone        VARCHAR(16)               ,
CONSTRAINT PK_CustomerID PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID));


CREATE TABLE Order_t
          (OrderID            INT        NOT NULL,
               OrderDate          DATE           NULL,
               CustomerID         INT        NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_OrderID PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
CONSTRAINT FK_CustomerID FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES customer_t(CustomerID));

CREATE TABLE Equipment
             (EquipmentID         INT        NOT NULL,
              EquipmentType       VARBINARY(12)      ,
              YearOfManufacture   INT                ,
              Cost                DECIMAL(9,2)       ,
          Maker               VARCHAR(45)        ,
          Model               VARCHAR(45)        ,
          CustomerID          INT                ,
CONSTRAINT EquipmentID_PK PRIMARY KEY (EquipmentID),
CONSTRAINT CustomerID_FK FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer_t(CustomerID));

CREATE TABLE Order_Line_t
              (OrderLineID        INT        NOT NULL,
              OrderID             INT        NOT NULL,
              EquipmentID         INT        NOT NULL,
              OrderLineCost       DECIMAL(9,2)       ,
CONSTRAINT OrderLineID_PK PRIMARY KEY (OrderLineID),
CONSTRAINT OrderID_FK1    FOREIGN KEY (OrderID) REFERENCES Order_t(OrderID),
CONSTRAINT EquipmentID_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (EquipmentID) REFERENCES Equipment_t(EquipmentID));

CREATE TABLE MaintenanceSchedule_t
             (MaintenanceID       INT         NOT NULL,
              MaintenanceType     VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
              Schedule_Date            DATE        NOT NULL,
              EquipmentID         INT         NOT NULL,
              ServiceID           INT                 ,
CONSTRAINT MaintenanceID_PK PRIMARY KEY (MaintenanceID),
CONSTRAINT EquipmentID_FK3 FOREIGN KEY (EquipmentID) REFERENCES Equipment(EquipmentID));

CREATE TABLE Service
             (ServiceID           INT          NOT NULL,
              EstimatedCost       DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL,
              Status              VARCHAR(16)  NOT NULL,
              ServiceDate         DATE                 ,
              EquipmentID         INT          NOT NULL,
              EmployeeID          INT          NOT NULL,
              ActualCost          DECIMAL(9,2)         ,
              ServiceType         VARCHAR(45)  NOT NULL,
              Notes               VARCHAR(2000)        ,

CONSTRAINT ServiceID_PK PRIMARY KEY (ServiceID),
CONSTRAINT EquipmentID_FK FOREIGN KEY (EquipmentID)  REFERENCES Equipment(EquipmentID));

CREATE TABLE Employee_t
             (EmployeeID          INT          NOT NULL,
              AnnualSalary        DECIMAL(9,2)         ,
              Name                VARCHAR(45)  NOT NULL,
              DOB                 DATE                 ,
              POSITION            VARCHAR(45)          ,
CONSTRAINT EmployeeID_PK PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID));
```

Comment: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=5784

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

set foreign_key_checks=0;
drop table energyefficient.customer_t;
set foreign_key_checks=1;

Some time it needs to set foreign key checks to 0;

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Possibility 1**:

Your table creation script does not have any error.

As per the error message shown:

```
"01:22:05   DROP TABLE customer_t   
Error Code: 1051. Unknown table 'energyefficient.customer_t'    0.016 sec"
```

You are trying to drop the table `customer_t` in a database named `energyefficient`.

Possible reason is that you have created the table in some other database and trying to drop from somewhere else.

**Possibility 2**:

You can modify the `drop table` to include `if exists` clause, so that the error is suppressed and ignored silently but with a warning, if such table does not exist.

**Example**:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customer_t;
```

In case if you are dropping the *parent* table first, change the global variable `foreign_key_checks` to `false` and run the drops.

```
set foreign_key_checks = 0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customer_t;
-- other drop statements here.
set foreign_key_checks = 1; -- reset to default
```